# Using Ubuntu 22.04 for ROS2 Humble, Ceres-Solver, PCL and Octomap

Tags: 22.04, cmake, ros

I am trying to use Ubuntu 22.04 for ROS2 Humble, Ceres-solver, PCL and Octomap. I keep on running issues with these programs. I downloaded ROS2 Humble as a debian and I think it works correctly but the ceres solver does not like to be downloaded. PCL and Octomap are all downloaded but whenever I am trying to clone the repository, it keeps on making errors. Any suggestions or step by step instructions would be highly appreciated.

I am currently following this guide from github.
https://github.com/wh200720041/ssl_slam

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written is unclear. You indicate that you "keep on running [into] issues" and "making errors" with the programs you mention, but you don't provide any details. What, specifically, are the issues? Please include any error output in your question. With this additional information, we might be able to solve your issues. Thanks

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting